# Call Object.prototype method on Global Scope

Tags: javascript

This code throws an error.

```
try {
  alert(hasOwnProperty('window'));
} catch(e) {
  alert(e); // Type Error : can't convert undefined to object
}
```

but this code doesn't throws an error.

```
try {
  alert(this.hasOwnProperty('window')); // true (if on browser)
} catch(e) {
  // through catch block
  alert(e);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iquhes/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iquhes/1/edit)

As far as I kwon, `func(arg)` is equal to `this.func(arg)` if `this` is Global Object. Why does such a thing happen?

Comment: *"As far as I kwon, `func(arg)` is equal to `this.func(arg)` if this is Global Object."* No, that's not correct, but if the code is running at global scope, and if you're not in strict mode, it can seem a bit like that.

Comment: Really fascinating question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* what's going on is that we have an interaction of strict mode code and non-strict mode code. And in fact, when I dug up a copy of Firefox 3.6.15 (which doesn't support strict mode), I don't get the error using the link I posted to your question (it alerts "true" twice).

The code you've shown is, obviously, non-strict mode code. But what about the `hasOwnProperty` implementation of the browser? I suspect it's strict, on browsers where strict mode is supported.

When you say

```
func();
```

...what the browser does is look up `func` using standard identifier resolution, and then call it as though you did this:

```
func.call(undefined);
```

If `func` is a loose-mode function, then within the call to `func`, `this` is the global object. **But**, if `func` is a strict-mode function, `this` within the call is `undefined`.

In contrast, with this:

```
this.func();
```

...it again looks up `func` (this time via property resolution using the prototype chain) and then effectively does this:

```
this.func.call(this);
```

In either strict or loose mode, that means `this` within the function will be `this`. (And of course, at global scope, `this` is the global object.)

Here's an example of this interaction using code we can see rather than `hasOwnProperty`:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  window.strictFunction = function() {
    display("strictFunction: this === window? " +
            (this === window));
    display("strictFunction: typeof this: " +
            typeof this);
  };

})();

strictFunction();
strictFunction.call(undefined);
```

As you can see, that's loose code except for the bit defining a `strictFunction` function on `window`. Then we *call* that function twice from loose code. The result is this:

```
strictFunction: this === window? false
strictFunction: typeof this: undefined
strictFunction: this === window? false
strictFunction: typeof this: undefined
```

In contrast, if we do that with a loose function, the result is:

```
looseFunction: this === window? true
looseFunction: typeof this: object
looseFunction: this === window? true
looseFunction: typeof this: object
```

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/emiquz/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/emiquz/2/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Fun With Strict Interactions</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      window.strictFunction = function() {
        display("strictFunction: this === window? " +
                (this === window));
        display("strictFunction: typeof this: " +
                typeof this);
      };

    })();
    (function() {

      window.looseFunction = function() {
        display("looseFunction: this === window? " +
                (this === window));
        display("looseFunction: typeof this: " +
                typeof this);
      };

    })();

    display("Direct call:");
    strictFunction();
    looseFunction();

    display("<hr>Call with <code>.call(undefined)</code>:");
    strictFunction.call(undefined);
    looseFunction.call(undefined);

    display("<hr>Call with <code>.call(window)</code>:");
    strictFunction.call(window);
    looseFunction.call(window);

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output (using a JavaScript engine that supports strict mode):

```
Direct call:
strictFunction: this === window? false
strictFunction: typeof this: undefined
looseFunction: this === window? true
looseFunction: typeof this: object
--
Call with .call(undefined):
strictFunction: this === window? false
strictFunction: typeof this: undefined
looseFunction: this === window? true
looseFunction: typeof this: object
--
Call with .call(window):
strictFunction: this === window? true
strictFunction: typeof this: object
looseFunction: this === window? true
looseFunction: typeof this: object
```

Comment: Thanks all answers! I understood all problems.

Comment: Good job... That's really something to have in mind and another reason that we should try writing code as close as possible to strict mode even if we are not in strict mode in our scripts. +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is one of *context*. That is to say, in essence, what the `this` value inside the function is when it's called.

Calling `hasOwnProperty('window')` does not have a context. It is the same as doing this:

```
hasOwnProperty.call(undefined, 'window');
```

Whereas `this.hasOwnProperty('window')` is the same as doing this:

```
hasOwnProperty.call(this, 'window');
```

The second line of code will have the output you expect (`true`), but the first one will obviously not work.

Comment: Note that unless you're using strict mode, `hasOwnProperty.call(undefined, 'window')` is effectively `hasOwnProperty.call(window, 'window')`. If you call a function without setting `this` explicitly (or passing `undefined` or `null` into `call` or `apply`), outside of strict mode, `this` is the global object. (And yet, that's not how it behaves -- http://jsbin.com/iquhes/7/edit -- and so there's something at play I'm just not quite getting.)

Comment: Ha! Great work. I was stumped on why `hasOwnProperty` was defined but the *call* was failing. JS and contexts can be really fascinating.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In that case, I confess myself a little stumped. Because strict mode certainly *isn't* enabled.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Actually, I think it may be. I'm thinking... if `hasOwnProperty` is defined in strict code in the browser implementation... one sec.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Yup! It's a strict thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So all native browser methods are effectively in strict mode? That makes a lot of sense and would be the missing link here. Thanks for your research!

Comment: @lonesomeday: I can't find anything in the spec saying that has to be true (nor anything saying it has to be false). But it would appear that `hasOwnProperty` is strict on Chrome 20something and Firefox 20. I dug up a copy of Firefox 3.6.15 (which doesn't have strict mode), and the OP's example alerts "true" twice. Fascinating!